# Kafka Streams Processor API clear state store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka Processor API to do some custom calculations. Because of some complex processing, DSL was not the best fit. The stream code looks like the one below.

```
KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("storeName");
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, StoreObject>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(storeSupplier,
            Serdes.String(), storeObjectSerde);   
topology.addSource("SourceReadername", stringDeserializer, sourceSerde.deserializer(), "sourceTopic")
.addProcessor("processor", () -> new CustomProcessor("store"), FillReadername)
.addStateStore(storeBuilder, "processor") // define store for processor
.addSink("sinkName", "outputTopic", stringSerializer, resultSerde.serializer(),
                    Fill_PROCESSOR);
```

I need to clear some items from the state store based on an event coming in a separate topic. I am not able to find the right way to probably join with another stream using Processor API or some other way to listen to events in another topic to be able to trigger the cleanup code in the CustomProcessor class.
Is there a way we can get events in another topic in Processor API? Or probably mix DSL with Processor API to be able to join the two and send events in any of the topic to the Process method so that I can run the cleanup code when an event is received in the cleanup topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another input topic (`add:Source`) and add Processor that transforms messages from that topic and based on them remove staff from state store. One note, those topics should use same keys (because of partitioning).

Comment: Thanks, one of the problems we have is that the second topic cannot not have the same keys. These will have some parent level keys, based on which I can iterate over the state-store entries and clean some of them.
Is there a way we can somehow get all the messages from the second topic in all the instances of the processors, something along the lines of a global K-Table.

Comment: @HarshKumar, maybe you should create some intermediate topic based on that `second topic` with changed keys that are the same like keys of the first one

Comment: Thanks Bartosz, I added the logic of sending same keys in the source applications. I had to add a lookup from parent key to child keys in the persistence store to find child keys that are the same as the keys in the first topic.